# Can use select into with multiple cte

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Can use select into with multiple cte? for example in the below code the result of the first cte cte_table is inserted into dbo.table1, then the other cte is defined. is this possible?

```
WITH cte_table 
AS 
( 
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table
)
INSERT INTO dbo.table1 
SELECT *
FROM [cte_table]
, cte_table2
AS
(
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.table2
)
```

Comment: This really makes no sense, don't you think so too?

Comment: what do you actually want to do for which you are trying thsis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your case is `Re-usability` of the record set, in that case use a Temp Table or Table variable.

e.g.

```
Select * Into #temp1 From dbo.table

INSERT INTO dbo.table1 
SELECT * FROM #temp1

SELECT * FROM #temp1 ..... and do some other re-usability operations.
```

A chained Cte work as under (just an example)

```
;With Cte1 As ( Select * from table1)
,Cte2 As (Select * from table2)

select c1.*,c2.*
from cte1 c1, cte2 c2
```

Hope you understand when to use what and how.

Answer (score 8):

Chain all your CTEs and THEN do the select into.

```
WITH First_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Columns
    FROM
        Schema.Table
    WHERE
        Conditions
),
Second_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Columns
    FROM
        Schema.OtherTable
    WHERE
        Conditions
)

SELECT
    Variables
INTO
    NewTable
FROM
    First_CTE A
JOIN
    Second_CTE B
ON
    A.MatchVar = B.MatchVar
```

This can be helpful if you have no need of the CTEs later but prefer a simpler method than subqueries for your ETL.

Answer (score 3):

No you can't: you get an error as `INTO` is not allowed, and, as others have pointed out, it makes sense as the `CTE` is intended to be a repeatable (and thereby static) reference.

And I recall reading somewhere that is/was in large part syntactical sugar, in so far as the cte is resolved out into a derived table when the sql is executed.

Comment: Not to mention that `SELECT ... INTO` doesn't return a result set anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No You cant use select into in CTE. And it actually does not make any sense also.